# (Flutter, Linux, VS code, Android Physical device) When write flutter run => lost connection to device

Tags: android, linux, flutter, visual-studio, connection

I am a novice flutter developer. When i write flutter run on my terminal to run my app on my Android phone i got => **lost connection to device.** Sometimes it runs well but when i discharged my phone from laptop then try to run my app it bombs. I could not open my  app. Any solutions?

```
flutter run
```

Launching lib/main.dart on SM
A105F in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                                5.3s
✓  Built
build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app
-debug.apk.
W/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate(  815): A splash screen was provided to Flutter, but this is deprecated. See flutter.dev/go/android-splash-migration for migration steps.
Syncing files to device SM A105F...                                   52ms

Flutter run key commands.
r Hot reload. 
R Hot restart.
h List all available interactive
commands.
d Detach (terminate "flutter run"
but leave application running).
c Clear the screen
q Quit (terminate the application
on the device).

Running with sound null safety

An Observatory debugger and
profiler on SM A105F is available
at:
http://127.0.0.1:33591/LuqkrIOJyV
4=/
The Flutter DevTools debugger and
profiler on SM A105F is available
at:
http://127.0.0.1:9101?uri=http://
127.0.0.1:33591/LuqkrIOJyV4=/
Lost connection to device.

*I deleted vs code and installed new version, deleted app and run it again, try to update android licences, update some of my phone's apps,*

Comment: Please, edit your question and mark flutter output as a code, to separate from the sentences written by yourself. Also clearify versions of the software used and environment.

Answer (score 0):

Now i am using 2.8 version stable it is fine. Alhamdulillah! I suggest you to move new version.